# Subtract dates to get the number of days

Tags: php, date

I am trying to write a php code which will be able to subtract two dates and get the number of days between the two dates. The code I came up with is given below

```
<?php
$c_date = date("Y-m-d");
//Subtracting two dates.
$date1 = new DateTime($d_date); //$d_date gets its value from database which i havent shown here
$date2 = new DateTime($c_date);
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
echo "difference " . $interval->y . " years, " . $interval->m." months, ".$interval->d." days ";
?>
```

Now the above code works but I am not able to use it to suit my needs. I need to be able to find out if the delivery date ($d_date) is within 5 days from the current date and return value 1 if that is that case.

So if `$c_date = "2013-09-24"` and `$d_date = "2013-09-30"` then I will be returning 1. 
But the trouble is when say the delivery date is "2013-09-19" the delivery date has long past and I should be returning 0, but with the current code the difference in day would still be 5 and so i will be returning 1 which is wrong.

Have any ideas as to how to overcome this?

Comment: add an if statement to compare the dates first (which one is greater etc.) and then use the logic you have for the 5 day difference ?

Comment: Where does your code return anything? It's just printing out the difference.

Comment: I havent shown the return, because the trouble is with the date difference, it can't differentiate between greater and lower dates so subtracting a lower date from higher date is also positive which is messing things up

Comment: @MarkBaker: Which he's already using

Comment: Thank you @Maximus2012 your idea put me in the right track silly of me to not think about it, I am posting the required script in the answer

Comment: DateInterval format of `%a`

Comment: check `$interval->invert` it will be 1 for past date :) `Is 1 if the interval is inverted and 0 otherwise`

Comment: didn't know about the `$interval->invert` thank you @JasonOOO this would be a better way to doing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so here is the required code, as Maximus2012 suggested, using a if statement to compare the dates first did the work. So here is the code

```
$date1 = new DateTime($ddate[$counter]);
                $date2 = new DateTime($c_date);
                if($date2>$date1)
                {
                    $stat = 0;
                }
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
                $d_diff = $interval->d;
if($d_diff>5)
{
$stat = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$interval = $date2->diff($date1);
$returnValue = $interval->d <= 5 && !$interval->invert;
```

`$returnValue` will be `true` or `false` (boolean type).

**EDIT:**
To be precise - To evaluate it to `1` or `0` you can do

```
$returnValue = (int) ($interval->d <= 5 && !$interval->invert);
```

**EDIT #2:**
`$interval->invert` is property telling you if the difference between `$date2` and `$date1` is negative(1) or positive(0). It's confusing - the calculation in `diff` method is always second object (method argument) *minus* first object (method callee) so if supposedly

```
$date1 > $date2
```

is true then

```
$date1->diff($date2)
```

is negative (in a shortcut).

Comment: what does !$interval->invert do ?

Comment: It tells you if the difference between dates is negative(1) or positive(0).

Comment: thanks for the update. I think this makes an efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could compare both the datetime objects and check if the delivery date's greater than the current date and proceed accordingly.

As a function:

```
function check_date($d_date, $c_date)
{
    if($d_date > $c_date) {
        $date1 = new DateTime($d_date); //$d_date gets its value from database which i havent shown here
        $date2 = new DateTime($c_date);
        $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
        return "difference " . $interval->y . " years, " . $interval->m." months, ".$interval->d." days ";
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Test case

```
var_dump( check_date('2013-09-30', '2013-09-24') );
var_dump( check_date('2013-09-19', '2013-09-24') );
```

Output:

```
string(37) "difference 0 years, 0 months, 6 days "
bool(false)
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/50521)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the number of days passed.  if so use this:

```
$interval = $date1->diff($date2)->days;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :D

```
function dateInterval($current, $delivery, $days){
    $unixCurrent = strtotime($current);
    $unixDelivery = strtotime($delivery);
    if ($unixCurrent === false || $unixDelivery === false){
        return -2;
    }
    if ($unixCurrent > $unixDelivery){
        return -1;
    } else if ($unixCurrent+($days*86400) > $unixDelivery){
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: this solution looks functional so not sure why it has been downvoted. Did you try running the code for different cases to see if it gives the correct output ? In either case there are more efficient ways to do this as posted in other solutions.

Comment: I know there are better ways to do it, but this one works I wrote it fast but works, idk why I got downvoted.