# Form Field type is Date DateDiff

Tags: php, date, datediff

I have a form with Start & End date fields. The user plugs in the dates and runs a report.

I'm trying to find the total number of days between these dates.

Currently the form fields are setup type=date. The date format is 01-01-2017.

I have tried a lot but this seems to have me pretty close.

```
$end_date = date("m-d-y", strtotime($endd));
$start_date = date("m-d-y", strtotime($startd));

$reportdays = ($syour_date - $eyour_date);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subtract dates to get the number of days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991584/subtract-dates-to-get-the-number-of-days)

Answer (score 0):

The date function is used to format a date for printing. It cannot be used to subtract two dates. You are basically trying to subtract two date strings.
`'2016-12-12' - '2017-01-12' == 'invalid!'`

You should use the DateTime:::diff() function to get the difference in days like this:

```
$end_date = new Date($endd);
$start_date = new Date($startd);
$interval = $end_date->diff($start_date);
$reportdays = $interval->format('%d');
```

You can read more about this here:
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: I tried this but I receive "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Date' not found"

Comment: I got it. Had to use DateTime() instead of Date(). Thanks for your help